# get values for the option box from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have been trying to get values for the option box from the database. I don't why this code isn't working. Please help

```
 <?php
     include_once "connection.php";
       $order ="SELECT * FROM seminar ";

       $result = mysql_query($order);

   ?>

       <?php

    echo '<div class="uk-form-row">';
    echo '<label class="uk-form-label" for="form-h-s">Description</label>';
    echo '<div class="uk-form-controls">';
    echo '<select name="description" id="form-h-s">';
    while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $options = '<option value="data[1]">data[2]</option>';
    echo $options;

    echo  '</select>';
    }
    echo   ' </div>';
    echo  '</div>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

`$options` will not work because you are writing literal text `data[1]` (instead of variable `$data[1]`); you also **cannot** use single quotes when calling variables variables; you need to use double quotes in order to use variable interpolation, like so:

```
$options = "<option value='$data[1]'>$data[2]</option>";
//         ^ double quote  ^ $ sign  ^ $ sign         ^ double quote
```

You also are writing the closing `</select>` tag *inside* your while loop. The whole thing needs to look like this:

```
echo '<select name="description" id="form-h-s">';
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo '<option value='$data[1]'>$data[2]</option>';
    //you don't even need to set the $options variable; just output it directly.
}
echo  '</select>';
```

**Footnote:**

`mysql_` is deprecated; highly recommend using [`mysqli_`](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or better [`PDO()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Well i do have php declaration on top. I forgot to include that (i edited my post now). Since there are some html code in between it is separated.

Comment: I made the changes 
$options = "<option value='$data[1]'>$data[2]</option>";
it seems to work now. thank you so much.

Comment: @lamahewa yep no problem! I get stuck with that one sometimes - both the $ and ', and sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes.

Comment: Well, it only returns the first row of the table. Not all the rows as i wanted. Any idea why?

Comment: do `print_r($result);` what does it output?

Comment: @lamahewa blat, that's not what I meant to say, oh well. I see your problem though - you're completing `</select>` in your while loop. See updated answer.